# Build cards in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to build this kind of cards, that are in the same row, and which can be scroll through horizontally. Can you recommend any tool for doing so?

[Cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8teui.jpg)

I'm using `display:flex` on my container but it doesn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the overflow -x auto of the parent div container of the card, make it a flex container and flex-wrap with nowrap.

something like this

```css
.parent-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.card-container {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 380px;
  background: green;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-container">
  <div class="card-container"></div>
  <div class="card-container"></div>
  ...
  <div class="card-container"></div>
  <div class="card-container"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> you can use `display-flex;` to parent div and with `flex-direction: row;`
>   to scroll add `overflow-x: auto; scroll-behaviour: smooth;` So it will adjust with you div element width;